# header hidden when I set a body background

Tags: html, css, background, header

here's the code I'm using. I want to set a header with an image background, but when I set the body background, it dissapear :S. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<body>
<div id="bg">
    <img src="img/bodyBackground.png">
</div>

<header>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Bienvenidos a JVasconcelos.me</h1>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

This is just the HTML code, here's the CSS I'm using:

```
#bg { position: fixed; top: -50%; left: -50%; width: 200%; height: 200%; }
#bg img { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;     margin: auto; min-width: 50%; min-height: 50%; }
```

Comment: why `top:-50%` and `left:-50%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add background image to body with css and it will show up.

You can then set a new background image with css by header { background: url(x) no-repeat; }

```css
#bg { position: fixed; top: -50%; left: -50%; width: 200%; height: 200%;  }
body {
  background: url('http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg') no-repeat;
  }
#bg img { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;     margin: auto; min-width: 50%; min-height: 50%; }
 header { background: url('http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/hubble_friday_03042016.jpg?itok=j1kZCJ51') no-repeat; }
```

```html
<body>

<header>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Bienvenidos a JVasconcelos.me</h1>
    </div>
</header>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: This one worked fine, but now the background image its not with the same size as the background.
Edit: Fixed using `body { background: url("../img/bodyBackground.png") no-repeat center center fixed; }`

Comment: Yea, just the image I was using. If you want it to repeat you could also take out the no-repeat, but I'd center it as you did.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for if you want to keep your markup the way it is.

It's because the header is hidden behind the background. You'll want to set z-index. So add `z-index: 0;` to your `#bg`. Then add the following styles to your header:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of manually adjusting your img to be a backgroud for your header, why don't you use this tag to set a background image?

`header{
    background-image: url("img/bodyBackground.png")
}`